# Пользовательский диапазон ERRCODE (SQLSTATE)

Tags: postgresql

При создании исключения в хранимке используется конструкция

```
RAISE EXCEPTION '<err_message>' USING ERRCODE = 'X0001';
```

Согласно документации первые два символа определяют класс ошибок, следующие 3 - код ошибки в классе.

Вопрос, какие коды допустимо использовать в ERRCODE, чтобы не получить коллизию с зарезервированными значениями?
(Могу ли я зарезервировать за своим набором хранимок диапазон FF000-FF999)

Зарезервированные SQLSTATE:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLSTATE
Документация постгре:
https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/errcodes-appendix

UPD:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594395/custom-error-code-class-range-in-postgresql

UPD2:
В оф доке https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html написано следующее:
When specifying an error code by SQLSTATE code, you are not limited to the predefined error codes, but can select any error code consisting of five digits and/or upper-case ASCII letters, other than 00000. It is recommended that you avoid throwing error codes that end in three zeroes, because these are category codes and can only be trapped by trapping the whole category.

В общем исходя из upd1 и upd2 можно вывести следующий набор правил:
* Нельзя использовать 00000
* Следует избегать **000 кодов
*Класс ошибок должен не совпадать с существующими ERRCODE
* Подкласс ошибки должен не совпадать с существующими ERRCODE

Простыми словами, можно все, что не зарезервировано.
Буду благодарен, если кто-то сможет подтвердить или опровергнуть мои догадки.